# SQLite writing limit is per database?

Tags: php, linux, database, sqlite

Since SQLite can only have one writing thread but many reads, I am wondering how this limit applies.

Is this per open connection to SQLite regardless of databases, or per each SQLite database? For example, if you connect PHP or Python to 4 SQLite databases, is the writing limit still 1 or is it 4 (one per database)?

Ultimately I want to know if I should separate some data in different databases to avoid hitting a concurrency limit?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does singular sequential writes, and it will queue if many threads and/or processes need to write the database at the same instant.

I wouldn't consider sharding until you hit performance issues, and even then I'd probably move up to a client server db (postgresql is easy to use).

You can read more about the sqlite concurrency at https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html.

Comment: I already use many other DB solutions such as MSQL, PostgreSQL and MariaDB. I am trying to design a new approach for something that will not rely on a centralized database server, hence SQLite fits the purpose as I need to transfer the databases between systems.
I do not plan to share the database to many users but one database per user. Hence my question. What limits should I consider if each user has its own SQLite database. I'm aware of that link but it does not really answer this particular question about concurrency.

Comment: ok, each sqlite file is a database and each database can only have 1 concurrent write process regardless of the number of connected users.  Also, it's not the end of the world if there are multiple write transactions as they will just queue.  So, I guess the exam question is how important is sub second latency for your readers?

Comment: Thanks, latency is not important here, they can wait if the query is eventually executed which I assume is true as you said they are put on a queue hold. 
I wonder much time until the queue expires by default. I think this answer my question. So, each database has its own independent write limit, it’s not per the whole platform or connector (PHP, Python, etc.)?